# Cordova Facebook Plugin - Error when calling for long-lived token

Tags: cordova, angular, facebook-graph-api

I have an Ionic 2 app and I am using the [Cordova Facebook 4 Plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4). Based on the documentation, I should be able to run some code that looks like this:

```
let url = `/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=<client-id>&
    client_secret=<client-secret>&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=${access_token}`;

    if(this.platform.is('cordova')) {


      Facebook.api(url, []).then(token => {

      }, error => {  this.error = JSON.stringify(token); });

    };
```

However, when I try to run this on my iOS device, I get an error that says: "There was an error making the graph call".

Is there something obviously wrong that I'm doing here? Do I need special permissions or anything? I can't seem to find the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So with this, I realized that instead of using the Facebook plugin, I was able to just use an Http GET request via Angular 2's Http service.

My code looks like this instead:

```
let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=<client-id>&
    client_secret=<client-secret>&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=${access_token}`;

this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {

      // Remove the "access_token=" string form the beginning of the token
      let token = data['_body'].slice(13);

      user['access_token'] = token;
    });
```

With that, I'm able to get the long-lived tokens which are supposed to last for 60 days. Cheers!